# firebase error messaging/authentication-error

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

where does the server key go when using firebase nodejs sdk.

I'm getting the error messaging/authentication-error, message: 'An error occurred when trying to authenticate to the FCM servers. Make sure the credential used to authenticate this SDK has the proper permissions.

however my sdk works in when handling authentications, so it's definitely initialized just not for messaging.

Comment: Have you reviewed this [setup guide](https://firebase.google.com/docs/admin/setup#add_firebase_to_your_app)?

Comment: @BobSnyder yeah i'm currently running firebase authentication and that works fine so admin is initialized.

Comment: solved it....... I updated my sdk to a new one which came out 12 hours ago and generated a new private key

Answer (score 18):

1. Go to GCP Dashboard in your project;
2. Search `API and Service`;
3. In the `Enable APIs and Services` section, click `+Enable APIs and Services`, and search `cloud messaging`;
4. Now go to `Cloud Messaging` and `Firebase Cloud Messaging API` one by one and enable it.

Comment: I want to comment that with new Firebase projects, only the new FCM API (v1) is enabled by default, with the legacy ("Cloud Messaging" API) being disabled by default. With that setup I always got auth error `PROJECT_NOT_PERMITTED` when trying to use the official `firebase-admin` Javascript library. I had to also enable the legacy API - as this answer does, or by using the Firebase console -> Project Settings -> Cloud Messaging -> Cloud Messaging API (Legacy) -> menu -> Manage API -> Enable.

Answer (score 0):

Go to google cloud
then go to API and Services
then Enabled API and Services
then turn on the cloud messaging
Turn on Firebase cloud messaging API.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).